# Api returns 404, but record is inserted in database

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I don't get it what the problem is (my code is working and i don't know why).
My api resource is working (since data is inserted in database), but i'm still getting 404 method not found.

This is my angular controller

```
controllers.tradeCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, userFactory, productsFactory, sessionFactory, $timeout, tradeFactory){
   $scope.sendTradeRequest = function () {
   var requestedUserId = $scope.user.id_user;
   var requestedUserItemsIds = $scope.i;
   var myRequestedItemsIds = $scope.o;
   tradeFactory.createTrade(requestedUserId, requestedUserItemsIds, myRequestedItemsIds).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
}
```

my factory

```
app.factory('tradeFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};
    factory.createTrade = function(requestedUserId, requestedUserItemsIds, myRequestedItemsIds){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/trades/makeTrade',
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data : $.param({
                requestuserId : requestedUserId,
                requestedUserItemsIds : requestedUserItemsIds,
                myRequestedItemsIds : myRequestedItemsIds
            })
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Failed to create new trade: ' + response);
        });
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

My rest controller made in codeigniter

```
class Trades extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Model_trades');
    }
    public function index_get(){
        $this->response($this->Model_trades->get_all());
    }
    public function newTrade_post(){
        $otherUserId = $this->input->post('requestuserId');
        $otherUserItemIds = $this->input->post('requestedUserItemsIds');
        $currentUserItemIds = $this->input->post('myRequestedItemsIds');
        $this->response($this->Model_trades->create($otherUserId, $otherUserItemIds, $currentUserItemIds));
    }
}
```

My model function in codeigniter for inserting new records

```
function create($otherUserId, $otherUserItemIds, $currentUserItemIds){
    $data = array(
        'request_id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
        'request_products' => $currentUserItemIds,
        'response_id_user' => $otherUserId,
        'response_products' => $otherUserItemIds,
        'date_c' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'id_status' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('trades', $data);
}
```

And finally console out put

```
POST http://myApp.com/server/api/trades/makeTrade 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765sendReq @ angular.js:10558serverRequest @ angular.js:10268processQueue @ angular.js:14792(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14808Scope.$eval @ angular.js:16052Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15870Scope.$apply @ angular.js:16160(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23618jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.js:4435elemData.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.js:4121
factory.js:266 Failed to create new trade: [object Object]
controllers.js:662 undefined
```

But new record is made in my database. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was in nginx. The cache didn't properly refreshed web page. After clearing cache, application is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your model function doesn't return anything so `$this->response` would not see a truthy return

Try

```
function create($otherUserId, $otherUserItemIds, $currentUserItemIds){
    $data = array(
        'request_id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
        'request_products' => $currentUserItemIds,
        'response_id_user' => $otherUserId,
        'response_products' => $otherUserItemIds,
        'date_c' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'id_status' => 1
    );
   return $this->db->insert('trades', $data);
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but this is not a case, since i already have other model written the way, my case is and they are working fine. I also tried your solution with returning result and problem remains. i'm investigating issue further

Comment: the problem was in nginx cache. :/